# C# CallerMemberName not working with dynamic in args?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a method that accepts a `dynamic` argument, and also has `[CallerMemberName]` on a different argument. The `[CallerMemberName]` argument doesn't get populated as long as the dynamic object is also in the arguments.

Is this a bug in the `CallerMemberName` or in C# itself? See below for a test

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new CMNTest().BaseMethod();
    }

    public void BaseMethod()
    {
        NormalMethod();
        dynamic myDyn = new Object();
        DynamicArgumentMethod(myDyn);
        ObjectArgumentMethod(new object());
        ObjectArgumentMethod((object)myDyn);
    }

    public void NormalMethod([CallerMemberName]string methodName = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(methodName);
    }

    public void DynamicArgumentMethod(dynamic dynObject, [CallerMemberName]string methodName = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(methodName);
    }

    public void ObjectArgumentMethod(object otherArg, [CallerMemberName]string methodName = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(methodName);
    }
```

Output:

```
BaseMethod
<null>
BaseMethod
BaseMethod
```

Tested in Visual Studio and LinqPad, same results. Any way around this? I need to do `dynamic` things with the object, so casting into an `object` won't work.

Comment: [Caller info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) values are emitted into the IL at compile-time. Dynamic expressions are evaluated at run-time, so the caller info is lost, and the default value (null in this case) is used. This isn't a bug.

Comment: Okay, is there any workaround besides looking for the membername before calling the method?

Comment: @sbat DynamicArgumentMethod itself is no dynamic expression though? It only has a dynamic parameter

Comment: @AndreasMüller Operations that contain an expression of type [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) are not resolved or type-checked by the compiler. The variable being passed in this code is a considered a dynamic expression, therefore the operation it's being passed to will be evaluated at run-time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is this a bug in the CallerMemberName or in C# itself?

No; the supposition that there is a bug at all is the error.

> C# CallerMemberName not working with dynamic in args?

That's correct. That's by design. It's not a bug.

> How does CallerMemberName work?

CallerMemberName works using the same mechanisms as optional arguments; if you don't understand those mechanisms then step one is to understand them. See my articles on the subject:

http://ericlippert.com/tag/optional-arguments/

Read those before you continue on.

.....

OK, now that you understand that optional arguments are *constants* that are *inserted by the compiler at the call site*, it should now be easier to understand how the caller attributes work. They are optional arguments which are replaced with the "constant" that is the location of the call site.

Now think about how "dynamic" works. "Dynamic" means "abandon analysis at compile time and start the compiler again at runtime; determine what the compiler *would have done* had it known the runtime types at compile time, and generate fresh code just like the compiler would have generated". **How does the compiler know to persist the current location as a constant into the call site?** The fact that it needs to do so is discovered **by compile-time overload resolution, which you just turned off**.

The compiler which runs at runtime does not have information about where in the source code the original call was; that information is not persisted into the call site because the original compile-time compiler has no reason to believe it needs to do so.

This is incidentally the same reason why extension methods cannot be dispatched dynamically: the call site payload does not include all the static classes that were "in scope" at the point of the call.

Unfortunately this is just one of the prices that you pay for fully dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The reason I'm using a dynamic is because I'm working with SignalR and I wanted to create a wrapper that lets me _not_ have to work with the dynamic objects as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

As sbat has mentioned, your method dispatch is happening dynamically because you've declared `myDyn` as `dynamic`. However, you don't actually need dynamic dispatch when calling `DynamicArgumentMethod` in order to treat your `dynObject` as `dynamic`.

If I'm not mistaken, this should work:

```
var myDyn = new object();
DynamicArgumentMethod(myDyn);
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Cool! That's simpler than I thought.

Comment: yup. this one results in the described desired behavior

Comment: Yeah, as long as I cast the `dynamic` to an object before I pass it it works: `DynamicArgumentMethod((object)myDyn);`

Comment: @DLeh There's no point to having it as dynamic in the first place if you're just going to cast it to object. Casting a method argument to `dynamic` is for when you want a method overload to be selected at runtime instead of compile time. You have no overloads of `DynamicArgumentMethod`, so there's no point in having the type of whatever you pass to `DynamicArgumentMethod` be dynamic.